# how to calculate average tenure of a worker in any factory

Tags: mean

I have tenure data for workers who have left the factory and also who are still working in the factory. I need to calculate average time spent by worker in the factory?. what data should i consider active workers or inactive workers.
when i considered active workers:
avg tenure = sum of number of years completed by active workers / total no of active workers.
i.e 3.5 years as the average number i am getting.

is this correct method ? because this is an on going event. some workers might have  just joined the factory so their tenure will be 0.1 to 0.9 years. this might pull the average down.
please let me know how to calculate average when the event is still going on.

Comment: At a glance this looks like a job for survival analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the data for both active and inactive worker. 
You can approach this in two ways.

First way: Calculate the median instead of mean. Median is less affected by outliers.

Second way: Consider a threshold year where if an employee has spent less year than the threshold value then you do not consider it in your calculation. Threshold value depends on you understanding of data. You can create box plot to decide on threshold value.

Comment: so i need to merge active and inactive tenure data and then calculate the average? also the factory is since 20 years but i have data for 2016 till now. and median for active workers is 2.7 years. but the question i have in hand ask for average tenure. Giving median value would be wrong. is there a way i can remove the outliers before calculating the mean?

Comment: Yes, you need to merge active and inactive employees tenure data.  Regarding outlier, you can do it in different ways. 

1. You can create the box plot of tenure. The values coming out of whiskers would be outliers. you can detect the values from the plot and remove it.      2. another method would be to divide the tenure value in 1% quantiles. if you see a significant jump in any of those 1% value in the upper or lower range, that would be your outlier.  I might be confusing you here. so I have provided you the link below.                    https://conversionxl.com/blog/outliers/